# Python - pyinstaller IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: accessing xlsx/docx on Windows

Tags: python, excel, windows, permission-denied

I've been experiencing weird problem with writing to xlsx/docx file on Windows machines. It seems, that is specific only for Windows. On Linux everything works.
Here is my codesample:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--filename', required=True, help='Filename')
def start(filename):
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    with open(abs_path, mode="w+") as file_handler:
        file_handler.write('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

When I run this script:

```
python pyin.py --filename test.xlsx
```

Everything works. Data is written to the file and there are no errors.

When I use pyinstaller for package this script to executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile pyin.py
```

And run it:

```
pyin.exe --filename test.xlsx
```

I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyin.py", line 14, in <module>
    start()
  File "site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
  File "site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
  File "site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
  File "site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
  File "pyin.py", line 10, in start
    with open(abs_path, mode="w+") as file_handler:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\test_py\\test.xlsx'
```

When I change the extension from xlsx to for example dat or txt, it works.

I' ve tested this on Linux and it worked on file test.xlsx.

I've tryed to set permissions to the direcotry that Everybody can have full access, but it does not work.
I run program from cmd where I was even Administrator and it did not help.

First time I've seen this issue with writing to xlsx/docx was when I run Flask app in virtual environment and used library openpyxl for manipulating excel sheets. I could not save my file because of this error.

If I open file in mode 'r' it opens without errors, but when I use anything connected to writing it throws.

Is anybody familiar with this kind of error? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem in windows and it gives me a lot of headaches
here is some solutions :

- open command line as administrator  and make sure your program is run as admin check a method  [here](https://superuser.com/a/968225/775057)
- or try to save your file folder where a user can read it easily like My Documents

Comment: I' ve tested running cmd as Administrator and it did not help. Moving files to my home directory did not solve the issue. Processed Files will not be saved in my home dirs.

Comment: running cmd as admin or running your exe as an admin??

Comment: Tested both. Run cmd as Admin and then run my pyin.exe from that cmd - suppose any subprocess from this cmd has Admin rights. Then I edited script - default file is test.xlsx and then run pyin.exe as Admin. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Antivirus that blocked my own script from saving files with those extensions...Found out when our company changed antivirus vendor.